# Sorting an array of string-integer identifiers (like "chapter3lesson11")

Tags: ruby, sorting

I want to sort my array:

```
p1q1
p1q10
p1q2
```

to this order:

```
p1q1
p1q2
p1q10
```

ie: By growing `p` integer, then by growing `q` integer.

I am trying with `ids.sort { |id| id.to_i }` constructs, but I am probably re-inventing the wheel... what's the most readable/simplest way to perform this sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is this:

```
>> arr.sort_by { |id| id =~ /^p(\d+)q(\d+)$/ ; [$1.to_i, $2.to_i] }
=> ["p1q1", "p1q2", "p1q10"]
```

Comment: Or that, but it was short enough to save that extra method call (`map`) and the extra array it would create. For more than two variables I'd do it your way though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with arbitrary depth, not just two levels:

```
ids.sort_by { |id| id.scan /\d+/ }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would to something like this:

```
def p_q_str_to_num(str)
  str =~ /p(\d+)q(\d+)/
  ($1+$2).to_i
end

a = ["p1q1", "p1q10", "p1q2"]
a.sort {|x,y| p_q_str_to_num(x) <=> p_q_str_to_num(y)}
```

Returns:

```
["p1q1", "p1q2", "p1q10"]
```

Comment: Adding `$1` and `$2` would sort `p8q6` before `p7q8`, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Okay, Michael's solution with sort_by is indeed more elegant than mine. :P

Comment: Err, isn't it exactly what he wants? I interpreted _"by growing p, then by growing q"_ as if he wants to have `p8q6` BEFORE `p7q8`.

Comment: I figured by ascending `p`s and then ascending `q`s, which would mean `p7qx` comes before `p8qx`. We'll need to wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: `p7qx` comes before `p8qx`

Comment: Meanwhile I did some benchmarks, Michael's solution with `sort_by` is about 20x times faster than my solution with `sort` here. So just adjust his solution to use `($1+$2).to_i` and you are fine. :)

Comment: btw, here is the link to the bechmark: [benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/1216151)